# NoSuchMethodError: oracle.forms.handler.IHandler.getApplet()Ljava/applet/Applet

Tags: java, oracle, oracleforms

Please help me to solve this exception. I am running this on oracle 11g forms.
i am using DirectPrint.java (pjc). to check click [here.](http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/article-6621538.html)
I am running this on Forms Applet version is 11.1.2.0

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: oracle.forms.handler.IHandler.getApplet()Ljava/applet/Applet;
>       at dsd.printing.DirectPrint.parseURL(DirectPrint.java:554)
>       at dsd.printing.DirectPrint.setProperty(DirectPrint.java:316)
>       at oracle.forms.handler.ComponentItem.setCustomProperty(Unknown Source)
>       at oracle.forms.handler.ComponentItem.onUpdate(Unknown Source)
>       at oracle.forms.handler.JavaContainer.onUpdate(Unknown Source)
>       at oracle.forms.handler.UICommon.onUpdate(Unknown Source)
>       at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onUpdateHandler(Unknown Source)
>       at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processMessage(Unknown Source)
>       at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processSet(Unknown Source)
>       at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onMessageReal(Unknown Source)
>       at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.onMessage(Unknown Source)
>       at oracle.forms.engine.Runform.processEventEnd(Unknown Source)
>       at oracle.ewt.lwAWT.LWComponent.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at oracle.ewt.lwAWT.LWComponent.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>   ...

Comment: You are missing some library wich get called

Comment: @nightfox79 Thanks, but i have solved the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issue myself. Problem was when i compiled the DirectPrint.java i was used dependency frmall.jar which was for 10g.
I have changed the frmall.jar from 10g to 11g and compile the java file and run. Its working.